# create-react-app material-ui persistant drawer different in build

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I created a persistent Material UI Drawer with the following example:

https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar

when i run it via npm start, it works as expected, and ducks under the appbar.

but upon running npm run build, the compiled app's drawer stays ABOVE the appbar.

in useStyles, i tried increasing the zIndex but it didn't change anything.

```
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 100,
  },
```

Comment: Could you share your code in `codesandbox`?

Comment: This issue isn't reproduceable in codesandbox because it requires npm run build and deployment to a webserver. But the example in https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar was followed faithfully.  it works as expected with npm start, fails when deployed.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/od0zu?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:
in makeStyles, the following worked in dev but not in deployed build:

```
  appBar: { //this doesn't translate on npm run build
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 100,
  },
```

**Resolution**:

I moved the zIndex change into the Theme and ThemeProvider

```
export const theme = createTheme({
...
    zIndex: {
        //just realize I could probably have zindexed the drawer here DOH
        appBar: 4000, //possibly use the 
        modal:4001
    },
```